# How long does it take for Chrome to Cache a file?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, caching

I was just wandering. I'm sure I'm not the only one wandering this.

I've been having some problems with Chrome caching .js files and them not being reloaded when I need them to be.

Does anyone know.. How long does it take for a file to get cached? Does it reset after some time? Does it reset after you restart your browser? Your computer? How many clicks does it take? One or many?

There are a bunch of questions. The main one is.. How does the caching system work on Chrome? (Or other browsers for that case..)

I don't really know that much about caching files. Haha.

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript files are cached the same as anything else. It caches them as soon as it downloads them, and expiration is based on the headers that the server sends. Cached files will be removed early if the cache fills up.

Comment: @Barmar Do you know any good way to prevent the files from being cached by the browser? I've done it before with PHP documents. But not HTML documents. I need a jQuery or JavaScript I guess...

Comment: Google "prevent browser caching js files" and you'll find lots of suggestions.